# Pass multiple values to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I built a for each loop that pulls back several rows from the database. Each row it pulls has a link, and a hidden input box with a value of posting_id. This link will work similar to a like button on facebook in a way. The hidden input box just stores the posting_id. When you click the "like" link, it sends over the posting_id to a jQuery page and pings back a page called community to tell it the user has "liked" the post.

**Here's the problem**

I'm pulling several rows, and it seems that only the top row being pulled is actually sending the data to the jQuery page when you click the "like" button. If I click on any other "like" button other than the top one it will not work at all.

**Jquery Page**

```
$('.bump_link').click(function(){ 
    var posting_id = $('.posting_id').val();    
    $.post("community.php", {
        posting_id: posting_id
    });
    alert(posting_id);
    $(this).toggleClass("bumped"); 
});
```

**Foreach Loop**

```
foreach ($result as $value) {
    $group_postings .= '
    <input type="text" class="posting_id" value="'.$value['posting_id'].'"> 
    <div id="bump_icon" class="bump_link"></div>
    <span id="counter"></span>
    ';
}
```

I hope I've made the issue clear, it was and is difficult to explain.

Comment: this code will result in an html error. You have assigned a static id to the elements within foreach loop. So you will end up having multiple 'bump_icon' and 'counter' ids in your html. This is not the proper way to deal with ids. ID must be unique to the element you assigned it.

Comment: I stripped a lot of the code for others to see the jist. I have id='$x', $x++ for each row's id.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are using a class to get the posting_id, since all the hidden fields have the same class only the first elements value is passed no matter what button you click.

i recommend using this html, without the hidden input,  pass the value as a data attribute

```
<div id="bump_icon" class="bump_link" data-postid="'.$value['posting_id'].'">
```

and in this js, get the posting id from the data attribute

```
$('.bump_link').click(function(){ 
   var posting_id = $(this).data('postid'); // get the posting id from data attribute
   $.post("community.php", {
       posting_id: posting_id
   });
   alert(posting_id);
   $(this).toggleClass("bumped"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `val()` on selector you might return more then one elements, but `val()` will give you the value of one (first) element only. You can use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to get all values of input having class `posting_id`

```
var posting_id_values = $('.posting_id').map(function(){
       return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
var posting_id = $('.posting_id').val();
```

This will return the first posting_id value every time, not the one associated with the bump_link you are clicking on.

There are lots of ways to solve this. One way is to use .prev() to select the previous element:

```
var posting_id = $(this).prev('.posting_id').val();
```

this selects the previous posting_id element from the current div. This relies on the fact that the posting_id element is before the associated bump_link div.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send just the `posting_id` of the clicked button, you could change your PHP/HTML code like this:

```
foreach ($result as $value) {
    $group_postings .= '
    <div id="bump_icon" class="bump_link">
    <input type="text" class="posting_id" value="'.$value['posting_id'].'"> 
    </div>
    <span id="counter"></span>
    ';
}
```

And your JS code like this:

```
$('.bump_link').click(function(){ 
    var posting_id = $(this).find('.posting_id').val();    
    $.post("community.php", {
        posting_id: posting_id
    });
    alert(posting_id);
    $(this).toggleClass("bumped"); 
});
```

Comment: Haha I see what you did! Brilliant! Worked great!

Comment: When I change class="posting_id" to id"posting_id" it wont work. Any thoughts why?

Comment: I changed find('.posting_id') to find('input[name=posting_id]') and it worked great!

Comment: ID should be unique, so you can't have more than 1 HTML element with the same ID. Class attribute instead can be used for this purpose. Why can't you use a class attribute?

Comment: I needed the class attribute for a style, name worked perfect.

Comment: Ok, but keep in mind that you can assign more than 1 class to each element, like `<input class="class1 class2 class3 posting_id" />`

Comment: What?! I must have been living under a rock! Thanks for the tip mate.

Answer (score 0):

use `on` delegated event since you are adding the content dynamically and

```
$(this).prev('.posting_id') // to get the posting data value

$(document).on('click','.bump_link',function(){ 
  var posting_id = $(this).prev('.posting_id').val(); //<-- use $(this)  reference 
  $.post("community.php", {
      posting_id: posting_id
  });
 alert(posting_id);
 $(this).toggleClass("bumped"); 
});
```